# Remove a list element based on condition

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list with many expressions as elements. I want to remove the list elements which do not contain certain variables. For example, I would like to remove the element which does not contain `x1` in the list `I` below:

`I = {2x1 + 3x2 - 5x1^2, 7x2 - 3x2^2, 2x1 + 5x2 - 9x3}`

to become

`I = {2x1 + 3x2 - 5x1^2, 2x1 + 5x2 - 9x3}`.

Also, I would like to combine conditions to check if the element does not contain any of a list of variables, and remove it if so. For example if neither `x1` nor `x2` in `I[[i]]`, then remove `I[[i]]`.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Removing elements which do not contain `x1` (i.e. keeping elements which do contain `x1`)

```
expr = {2 x1 + 3 x2 - 5 x1^2, 7 x2 - 3 x2^2, 2 x1 + 5 x2 - 9 x3};
Select[expr, MemberQ[Variables[#], x1] &]
```

> {2 x1 - 5 x1^2 + 3 x2, 2 x1 + 5 x2 - 9 x3}

Keeping elements which contain at least one of the variables from a list

```
(* changing example list to include a term which contains neither `x1` or x2` *)
expr = {2 x1 + 3 x2 - 5 x1^2, 7 x2 - 3 x2^2, 2 x1 + 5 x2 - 9 x3, x3 + x4};
wanted = {x1, x2};

Select[expr, 
 Table[MemberQ[Variables[#], v], {v, wanted}] /. List -> Or &]
```

> {2 x1 - 5 x1^2 + 3 x2, 7 x2 - 3 x2^2, 2 x1 + 5 x2 - 9 x3}

Answer (score 8):

```
list = {2 x1 + 3 x2 - 5 x1^2, 7 x2 - 3 x2^2, 2 x1 + 5 x2 - 9 x3, Sin[x1 + x4] + x5};
```

You can use [`FreeQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FreeQ.html) with [`DeleteCases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteCases.html), [`Cases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html), [`Select`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html) and [`Pick`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pick.html) as follows:

```
DeleteCases[_?(FreeQ[x1])]@list

Cases[_?(Not@*FreeQ[x1])]@list

Select[Not@*FreeQ[x1]]@list

Pick[list, Not @* FreeQ[x1] /@ list]
```

All methods above return

> {2 x1 - 5 x1^2 + 3 x2, 2 x1 + 5 x2 - 9 x3, x5 + Sin[x1 + x4]}

To delete cases that does not contain `x2` or `x3` (to keep only those case that contain both `x2` and `x3`)  use [`Alternatives (|)`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Alternatives.html) in the pattern inside `FreeQ`:

```
wanted =  {x2, x3};
alt = Alternatives @@ wanted;

DeleteCases[_?(FreeQ[alt])]@list

Cases[_?(Not@*FreeQ[alt])]@list

Select[Not@*FreeQ[alt]]@list

Pick[list, Not @* FreeQ[alt] /@ list]
```

All four methods give

> {2 x1 - 5 x1^2 + 3 x2, 7 x2 - 3 x2^2, 2 x1 + 5 x2 - 9 x3}

You can also use a combination of [`Level`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Level.html) and [`ContainsNone`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContainsNone.html) or [`ContainsAny`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContainsAny.html) as follows:

```
DeleteCases[_?(ContainsNone[Level[#, {-1}], wanted] &)]@list

Cases[_?(ContainsAny[Level[#, {-1}], wanted] &)]@list

Select[ContainsAny[Level[#, {-1}], wanted] &]@list

Pick[#, ContainsAny[Level[#, {-1}], wanted] & /@ #] &@list
```

to get

> {2 x1 - 5 x1^2 + 3 x2, 7 x2 - 3 x2^2, 2 x1 + 5 x2 - 9 x3}

**Note:** [`Variables`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Variables.html) *"gives a list of all independent variables in **a polynomial**"*:

```
Variables /@ list
```

> {{x1, x2}, {x2}, {x1, x2, x3}, {x5, Sin[x1 + x4]}}

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will have to accept the first answer since it was posted earlier and also because it provides a better way for dealing with many variables to exclude. Great answer though.

Comment: @Bran, you are welcome.